# No DBus signal available for Wake event in linux

Tags: 20.04, dbus, events

I wanted to perform some task in my application, as soon as the application wakes from sleep mode. To do that I wanted to detect the wake event in my application. In the 'org.freeDesktop.login1' interface, there is a signal 'PrepareForSleep' available to detect the sleep event, however, there is no counterpart DBus signal available to detect the wake event. Either it is not available or I m not able to find the signal. Can someone help me?